# ruby - Sum consecutive duplicate numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, sum, conditional-statements

So let's say I have a list/array which contains only integers (positive and negative). I want to make a method that gets the sum of only the numbers that are the same and consecutive. The result should be an array as shown in examples below.
The 'same' condition meaning: 1 == 1

Examples:

```
[1,4,4,4,0,4,3,3,1] # => [1,12,0,4,6,1]
So as you can see sum of consecutives 1 is 1 
sum of 3 consecutives 4 is 12 
sum of 0... and sum of 2 
consecutives 3 is 6 ...

[1,1,7,7,3] # => [2,14,3]
[-5,-5,7,7,12,0] # => [-10,14,12,0]
```

I tried this, but it doesn't have the consecutive condition, how would I add that condition?

```
def sum_consecutives(string)
  string.map{|num| string.count(num) > 1 ? num * string.count(num) : num}
end
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the original Array into chunks of consecutive numbers: [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while)

```
a = [1,4,4,4,0,4,3,3,1]
a.chunk_while {|a,b| a == b }
#=> [[1], [4, 4, 4], [0], [4], [3, 3], [1]]
```

Then just map and sum the sub arrays: [`Enumerable#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum)

```
a.chunk_while {|a,b| a == b }.map(&:sum) 
#=> [1, 12, 0, 4, 6, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the chunk enumerator, worked well. Btw I ended up with this:  string.chunk_while {|a,b| a == b; }.to_a.map{|set| set.count*set[0]}

Comment: @SamP `to_a` is not necessary and just creates an intermediary `Array` that is disposed of instead you can use `map` immediately afterwards e.g. `a.chunk_while {|a,b| a == b }.map{|set| set.size*set.first}`